# Ajax function give error "Hit error fn! [object Object]" from the following function when calling a webservice

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, web-services, sendmail

i am new to the webservice and try to call a webservice from html page which give me following error "Hit error fn![object Object]" and cannot sending mail to the desired email address. kindly tell me that whats the error?

```
function test() {

    var firstname=$('#txtName').val();
    var lastname =$('#txtMessage').val();
    var Email=$('#txtEmail').val();

    $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost/ZeroDebt/WsZeroDebtApp.asmx/SendEmailToClient",    
    data: { _fromAddress: JSON.stringify(Email),_Subject:JSON.stringify("Zero Debt App Invitation Request"),_body:JSON.stringify(firstname +' '+lastname), clientName: JSON.stringify('Dr. Hanoi'), clientEmail: JSON.stringify('abc@xyz.net') },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Hit error fn!" + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should use `console.log( error )` because its trying to stringify your response object. Its not a plain error message but an object holding information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, i found a solution. the only thing i need to do is to give email at client email parameter that would not be in string format. write abc@xyz.com instead of "abc@xyz.com".

the correct scenario is:
data: { _fromAddress: JSON.stringify(Email),_Subject:JSON.stringify("Zero Debt App Invitation Request"),_body:JSON.stringify(firstname +' '+lastname), clientName: JSON.stringify('Dr. Hanoi'), clientEmail: abc@xyz.net }

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to rewrite as such? (Please test yourself)

```
var SENDMAIL_URL = "http://localhost/ZeroDebt/WsZeroDebtApp.asmx/SendEmailToClient"

function test() {

  var firstname = $('#txtName').val(),
      lastname = $('#txtMessage').val(),
      email = $('#txtEmail').val();

  var data = JSON.stringify({
    _fromAddress: email,
    _Subject: "Zero Debt App Invitation Request",
    _body: firstname + ' ' + lastname,
    _clientName: 'Dr. Hanoi',
    clientEmail: 'abc@xyz.net'
  });

  function notify( args ) {
    console.log( args );
  }

  function onSuccess( data ) {
    notify( data );
  }
  function onError( error ) {
    notify( "Hit error fn!" ); // Important to seperate string from Object
    notify( error );
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: SENDMAIL_URL,    
    data: data,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
  });
}
```

Furthermore it would be maintainable to make your URL a constant string and keep urls together (easier configurable than scrolling through code).

Comment: EricG this function is still calling an error message.

Comment: I understand but you will be able to get details of the error once you split the string message from the error response object.

Comment: it gives the same error ([object Object]) on placing alert in error function. the function mentioned above didn't display any thing